# Restore Ubuntu desktop after installing Lubuntu desktop and how to remove these extra workspace

Tags: 20.04

I am new to the Linux platform and need to work on ubuntu but by mistake, I delete some desktop files and installed Lubuntu desktop which is really not much attractive and now I want to go back to the official Ubuntu 20.04 default settings. Is there any way to do this through sudo commands?

Answer:

Thank you so much for everyone. Your answers helped me to manage the Ubuntu workspace. –

But now I have one more question not relevant to the above one but now at the time of login to the user account I can see many workspaces like Ubuntu 2 times and LXQT desktop (for reference I attached an image below with the previous question), now my question is how to remove those or these are pre-installed options for user-dependent choice to use any like in android to use different themes?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFncM.png)

Comment: If you erased files on the desktop, then just create a new account.  Log into the account and copy the files back over (or just use the new account instead).

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu or Lubuntu? In case you installed Lubuntu, you can install the Ubuntu's default interface with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and choose it during login (alternatively reinstall Ubuntu).

Comment: You've tagged your release as 14.04, but indicate in text you're running 20.04. Please clarify your OS & release.  You can have multiple desktops installed; and you select at login which you want to use for that session (but how you do that varies on release & which DM you opted to use; `gdm3` being the default for Ubuntu 20.04 & `sddm` being the default for Lubuntu 20.04; if you have both installed you were asked which you want to use). At login select "Ubuntu" as your desktop session.

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone. Your answers helped me to manage the Ubuntu workspace.

Comment: But now I have one more question not relevant to the above one but now at the time of login to the user account I can see many workspaces like Ubuntu 2 times and LXQT desktop (for reference I attached an image above with the previous question), now my question is how to remove those or these are pre-installed options for user-dependent choice to use any like in android to use different themes?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question if you have another question on a new topic. Your picture shows a lot of packages have been added; or you system was upgraded from a LXDE release to a LXQt one (which is unsupported as issues occur that need to be manually fixed, but your question text didn't specify *release-upgrade*)  Installing Lubuntu would only cause Lubuntu, LXQt Desktop & a single Openbox to appear (Lubuntu with all Lubuntu configs, LXQt for purer usptream, & `openbox` is provided with Lubuntu as it needed by Lubuntu so we allow users to use it without LXQt/Lubuntu scripts)

Comment: LXDE is not Lubuntu (on any release after 18.04) so you've added a lot more than just Lubuntu....  If you add packages by command, you can use the `history` command to view your command history; if you use package tools you'll need to use apt logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) though you can use them for command installs too.

Comment: If you don't mind, can I ask you the solution "how to remove these extra workspace" here without creating a new question perhaps I will add the new question in the title bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu since 18.10 has used the LXQt desktop which uses the Qt5 toolkit, so very few settings of Ubuntu desktop are altered.

There are exceptions, eg. in the Appearance setting (see [the manual page on it](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html))

[image]

there is a checkbox "Set GTK themes (GTK configuration files will be overwritten!") which will cause some configuration of the Ubuntu (GNOME) desktop to change, but you can work around that (uncheck that box!)

Your picture (what appears to be `gdm3` but you weren't specific) shows a lot of packages have been added and not just Lubuntu; or your system was upgraded from a LXDE release to a LXQt one (w*hich is unsupported as issues occur that need to be manually fixed, but your question text didn't specify release-upgrade*)

Installing Lubuntu would only cause

- Lubuntu,
- LXQt Desktop, &
- a single Openbox to appear

A *Lubuntu* session runs with all Lubuntu configs, a *LXQt Desktop* session exists for *purer* upstream experience (*not all Lubuntu changes are present*), & `openbox` is provided with Lubuntu as it needed by Lubuntu so we allow users to use it without the LXQt Desktop & Lubuntu scripts).

The [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/) applies to the Lubuntu session.

LXDE is not Lubuntu (**on any release after 18.04**) so you've added a lot more than just Lubuntu....

If you add packages by command, you can use the `history` command to view your command history; if you use package tools you'll need to use apt logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) though you can use them for command installs too.  This will show you what you've installed, and thus how to reverse (ie. what to remove).

Answer (score 0):

I do have something similar, I installed Lubuntu and didn't like it, but after removing it My computer still have the Lubuntu loading screen. I also have an installation of GNOME, but for some reason I have in my desktop launch list (or whatever it's called) I have 2 versions of GNOME, 2 versions of "GNOME Destop", Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu on Wayland, and LXQt Desktop. They haven't caused me issues but I don't think they should be there.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by Lubuntu loading screen; if it's the `plymouth` screen then that's expected (a wallpaper type image that hides the system boot messages appearing at boot & shutdown; it's installed by a desktop package but is not removed on any desktop removal as its removal can break a system if alternatives don't exist (*already installed*)..  users need to change that themselves (it's only a low-res `png` & script that shots dots etc anyway so is small); https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo